# What is the new format for rake tasks? (task :t, arg, :needs => [deps] versus task :t, [args] => [deps])

Tags: rake, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm using Rails 3.1 beta with Ruby 1.9.2 and rake 0.9.2, and have a bunch of rake tasks I've written. Here is an example:

```
namespace :data do
  desc "dump the nodes and edges for a graph"
  task :dump_graph, :species_id, :needs => :environment do |t,args|
    args.with_defaults(:species_id => 'Hs')
    # ...
  end
end
```

When my rails app loads these rake tasks, however, I now get the following warning repeated once for each rake task:

```
    at /home/user/railsapp/lib/tasks/data/dump_graph.rake:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
WARNING: 'task :t, arg, :needs => [deps]' is deprecated.  Please use 'task :t, [args] => [deps]' instead.
```

I've experimented with rearranging the arguments in several different ways, but I'm not clear on exactly what my task should look like now.

Does rake expect me to give the individual dependencies? How do I define these in a rake task if the dep is the rails environment?

A link to updated documentation would be an acceptable answer! I've Googled and Googled, but no luck.

(And yes, I realize that the format is given in the error message. But that format does not appear to be correct, based on the variations I've tried.)

Comment: I'm having this problem as well but the solution is not working. I even have a rake task without arguments and it doesn't work either. My syntax is as follows: 'task :task_name => :environment do ... end'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know it is sometimes hard to decipher but the error message gives you the new format:

```
task :t, [args] => [deps]
```

So for your example:

```
task :dump_graph, :species_id => :environment
```

http://www.postal-code.com/binarycode/2011/06/02/rake-needs-deprecated/

Comment: Oddly when I was experimenting with this I couldn't get it to work, but it does now. I got it to work by doing: `task :dump_graph, [:species_id] => [:environment]`. Apparently the list on the right-hand side is optional if you've only got one dep.

Answer (score 9):

The usage which works for me is:

```
task :task_name, [:argument] => :environment
```

I guess if you had several dependencies to list, deps would need the array notation.

I've no idea why a single argument requires the array notation - running the rake task with --trace gives an error about the :argument symbol not responding to the empty? method.