# Change to Rake tasks and argument structure in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have seen the other posts but I am still having trouble. Below is my code. I have several rake tasks where I pass in zero, one or even five arguments. What am I missing?

```
namespace :my_namespace do
  desc 'shows user accounts within the database for the specified customer.'
  task :show_user_accounts, [:customer_id] => :environment do |t, args|

    cust = Customer.find( args.customer_id.to_i )
    cust.users.each do |user|
      puts "User Name: #{user.name}\tUser ID: #{user.id}\t"
    end
  end
end
```

I am running the task with the following command:

```
$ rake my_namespace:show_user_accounts customer_id=110
```

Error:

```
rake aborted!
Couldn't find Customer with id=0
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270671/what-is-the-new-format-for-rake-tasks-task-t-arg-needs-deps-versus-ta

Comment: @ScottJShea, not really. It is what I based my revised syntax on and I can't see why it isn't working. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much searching around I found that not only did the syntax for a rake task change, but the execution syntax did as well. So, the code of my rake task (above) is correct but my invocation was wrong.

The correct way for running above rake task is:

```
$ rake my_namespace:show_user_accounts[110]
```

I found the answer here: http://www.redconfetti.com/2012/01/example-rake-task/

Comment: the linked article id wrong and can't be found on the linked website!

Comment: When I do this, I get a message saying that the task[whatever] cannot be found, while the task without parameters works just fine...